# Coercing List of List Individual Elements to Vector Type

Tags: r, list, sorting, coerce

I'm using the permn function from CRAN package combinat to produce a list of lists composed of all the permutations of a range of numbers as follows

```
x <- str(permn(3))
x

List of 6
$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
$ : int [1:3] 1 3 2
$ : int [1:3] 3 1 2
$ : int [1:3] 3 2 1
$ : int [1:3] 2 3 1
$ : int [1:3] 2 1 3
```

I also have

```
typeof(x[[1]])
"integer"
```

My goal is to sort this list of lists in ascending numerical order (each element needs to be treated as a three digit number), and while the following works correctly

```
permn(3)->x
x[order(sapply(x,'[[',1))]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 2
...
```

any permn(n) n>3 yields an incorrect sorting. I realize that my issue is that I am sorting on individual values rather than n digit numbers, but I can't figure out how to decompose, sort, and then recompose correctly. I've tried

```
function(n){
out <-list()
permn(n)->list.of.lists
for(i in 1:length(list.of.lists)){
out[[length(out)+1]] <- unlist(list.of.lists[i])
}
out
```

but it gives the same results as

```
x[order(sapply(x,'[[',1))]
```

namely, I don't have each element ordered in the context of the other elements I'm working with.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a permn-package in CRAN. And I wasn't able to find a `permn` function in package:perm, so I'm not able to reproduce you results.

If `x` is a list, then `x[1]` will also be a list, so your efforts with `typeof(x[1])` are not telling you what the first element is. You should be using `typeof(x[[1]]` if you want to see what is in the first sublist of `x`. The `print` output shows you it is a list of integer vectors. If you want a list of vectors sorted, then use:

```
 lapply( x, sort)
```

The suggestion to use `sapply` will return a matrix. I'm assuming that you are using `permn` just to create an example since as I understand your request, it would be to produce the same result as `rep(list(1,2,3), 6)`.

If you want these paste()-d together as the basis of the sort/order operation then use:

```
x[ order( sapply(x, paste0, collapse=".")) ]
```

or, more efficiently, avoiding type coercion (although more verbose)

```
x[order(vapply(x, function(y) sum(y * 10^((length(y)-1L):0)), numeric(1)))]
```

or pull the multiplier out first,

```
mult <- 10^((length(x[[1]])-1L):0)
x[order(vapply(x, function(y) sum(y * mult), numeric(1)))]
```

Comment: Post edited. My R naivety is showing a bit... This solution works wonderfully. Much better than my non-R way of looping through each element.

Comment: @TheTime. I'm not sure that type coercion is necessarily less efficient. The decimal expansion method needs to do arithmetic calculations. It is a testable question, of course.